# captive core does not work

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, xlm, stellar.toml

I want to use the captive core of stellar-horizon v2.0.0, but the following command does not work.
Instance is building a new.

As far as I read the docs, I don't think it will make http requests to core by default.
Is this a bug?

> A. a subprocess of Horizon, streaming ledger data over a filesystem pipe. This is the default:
> https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/master/services/horizon/internal/docs/captive_core.md#introduction

My command and config are:

```
$ sudo -u stellar stellar-horizon \
--db-url="postgres://stellar:stellar123@localhost/horizon?sslmode=disable" \
--network-passphrase="Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015" \
--stellar-core-binary-path="/usr/local/bin/stellar-core" \
--captive-core-config-append-path="/etc/default/stellar-captive-core-stub.toml" \
--enable-captive-core-ingestion="true"
```

```
WARN[2021-03-15T10:19:58.017Z] could not load stellar-core info: http request errored: Get "http://localhost:11626/info": dial tcp [::1]:11626: connect: connection refused  pid=19811
INFO[2021-03-15T10:19:58.023Z] Starting horizon on :8000 (ingest: false)     pid=19811
WARN[2021-03-15T10:19:59.017Z] could not load stellar-core info: http request errored: Get "http://localhost:11626/info": dial tcp [::1]:11626: connect: connection refused  pid=19811
ERRO[2021-03-15T10:19:59.017Z] failed to load the stellar-core info          err="http request errored: Get \"http://localhost:11626/info\": dial tcp [::1]:11626: connect: connection refused" pid=19811 stack="[main.go:43 client.go:67 app.go:216 app.go:410 asm_amd64.s:1373]"
WARN[2021-03-15T10:20:00.017Z] could not load stellar-core info: http request errored: Get "http://localhost:11626/info": dial tcp [::1]:11626: connect: connection refused  pid=19811
ERRO[2021-03-15T10:20:00.017Z] failed to load the stellar-core info          err="http request errored: Get \"http://localhost:11626/info\": dial tcp [::1]:11626: connect: connection refused" pid=19811 stack="[main.go:43 client.go:67 app.go:216 app.go:410 asm_amd64.s:1373]"
ERRO[2021-03-15T10:20:01.017Z] failed to load the stellar-core info          err="http request errored: Get \"http://localhost:11626/info\": dial tcp [::1]:11626: connect: connection refused" pid=19811 stack="[main.go:43 client.go:67 app.go:216 app.go:410 asm_amd64.s:1373]"
WARN[2021-03-15T10:20:01.017Z] could not load stellar-core info: http request errored: Get "http://localhost:11626/info": dial tcp [::1]:11626: connect: connection refused  pid=19811
INFO[2021-03-15T10:20:01.967Z] Finished request                              app_name=undefined app_version=undefined bytes=3840 client_name=undefined client_version=undefined duration=0.000649964 forwarded_ip= host="localhost:8000" ip="[::1]" ip_port="[::1]:53090" method=GET path=/ pid=19811 referer=undefined req=ip-10-10-0-191.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal/06FSDb1on8-000001 route=/ status=200 streaming=false
INFO[2021-03-15T10:20:01.979Z] Finished request                              app_name=undefined app_version=undefined bytes=579 client_name=undefined client_version=undefined duration=0.000247862 forwarded_ip= host="localhost:8000" ip="[::1]" ip_port="[::1]:53094" method=GET path=/fee_stats pid=19811 referer=undefined req=ip-10-10-0-191.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal/06FSDb1on8-000002 route=/fee_stats status=200 streaming=false
WARN[2021-03-15T10:20:02.017Z] could not load stellar-core info: http request errored: Get "http://localhost:11626/info": dial tcp [::1]:11626: connect: connection refused  pid=19811
```

```
$ cat /etc/default/stellar-captive-core-stub.toml 
[[HOME_DOMAINS]]
HOME_DOMAIN="MYDOMAIN"
QUALITY="HIGH"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="sdf_live_1"
HOME_DOMAIN="stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GCGB2S2KGYARPVIA37HYZXVRM2YZUEXA6S33ZU5BUDC6THSB62LZSTYH"
ADDRESS="core-live-a.stellar.org:"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_001/{0} -o {1}"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="sdf_live_2"
HOME_DOMAIN="stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GCM6QMP3DLRPTAZW2UZPCPX2LF3SXWXKPMP3GKFZBDSF3QZGV2G5QSTK"
ADDRESS="core-live-b.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_002/{0} -o {1}"

[[VALIDATORS]]
NAME="sdf_live_3"
HOME_DOMAIN="stellar.org"
PUBLIC_KEY="GABMKJM6I25XI4K7U6XWMULOUQIQ27BCTMLS6BYYSOWKTBUXVRJSXHYQ"
ADDRESS="core-live-c.stellar.org"
HISTORY="curl -sf http://history.stellar.org/prd/core-live/core_live_003/{0} -o {1}"
```

Can you tell me the boot options or configs that captive core works for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `--ingest` option. By default Horizon instances are not ingesting ledger data, just starting the API server. I created [this issue](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/3473) to make params validation more strict.

Comment: I added the --ingest option, but the situation did not change.
Thank you.

Comment: Any new errors in the logs?